# str ireplace PHP parts of url

Tags: php, str-replace

I have a html doc that has links in it.

Example :

```
http://mysite1.com/test/whatIwant/Idontwantthis
http://mysite1.com/test/whatIwant2/Istilldontwantthis
http://mysite1.com/test/whatIwant3/Idontwantthiseither
```

I want to replace these with:

```
http://myothersite.com/whatIwant
http://myothersite.com/whatIwant2
http://myothersite.com/whatIwant3
```

How can I do this? I feel like the only way is to use str_ireplace to get the value that I want and append it to the other link, I just can't seem to remove the part after the value that I want.

I use:

```
$var= str_ireplace("http://mysite1.com/test/", "http://myothersite.com/", $var);
```

But then I get the after value still on the link:

```
http://myothersite.com/whatIwant/Idontwantthis
```

I tried and now am turning to the community for help.

Thanks

Oh and they are enclosed in the  tag with class and other attributes, all I need to change is the URL as explained above.

The links are not in an array they are being edited from a javascript file so they will be in a large variable as text.

```
    $examples = 
    'http://mysite1.com/test/whatIwant/Idontwantthis http://mysite1.com/test/whatIwant2/Istilldontwantthis http://mysite1.com/test/whatIwant2/Istilldontwantthis
    http://mysite1.com/test/whatIwant3/Idontwantthiseither'
;
```

Comment: I think you are looking for `.htaccess`

Comment: No I'm not I need to do this in the php file.

Comment: explode on / build from there

Comment: Or use a regex replace like this: http://regex101.com/r/aH2yZ0

Comment: @scrowler I think it is now how do I use this?

Answer (score 1):

**Edit:** using your updated example, you can split those URLs up by the whitespace between them:

```
$examples = 'http://mysite1.com/test/whatIwant/Idontwantthis http://mysite1.com/test/whatIwant2/Istilldontwantthis http://mysite1.com/test/whatIwant2/Istilldontwantthis http://mysite1.com/test/whatIwant3/Idontwantthiseither';
$examples = explode(' ', $examples);
```

**Alternative example array:**

```
$examples = array(
    'http://mysite1.com/test/whatIwant/Idontwantthis',
    'http://mysite1.com/test/whatIwant2/Istilldontwantthis',
    'http://mysite1.com/test/whatIwant3/Idontwantthiseither'
);
```

## Regex solution:

```
$pattern = '/^(?:http|https):\/\/.+\/.*\/(.+)\/.*$/Um';
$replace = 'http://myothersite.com/$1';

foreach($examples as $example) {
    echo preg_replace($pattern, $replace, $example);
}
```

## Non-regex solution:

```
foreach($examples as $example) {
    // remove the original domain name
    $first = str_ireplace('http://mysite1.com/test/', '', $example);
    // prepend the new domain name with the first part of the remaining URL
    // e.g. strip everything after the first slash
    echo 'http://myothersite.com/' . explode('/', $first)[0];    
}
```

**Note:** using `explode(...)[0]` is [array dereferencing](http://www.php.net/releases/NEWS_5_4_0_alpha1.txt), and is supported in PHP >= 5.4.0. For previous versions of PHP, use a variable to store the array before referencing it:

```
$bits = explode('/', $first);
echo 'http://myothersite.com/' . $bits[0];
```

From the manual:

> As of PHP 5.4 it is possible to array dereference the result of a function or method call directly. Before it was only possible using a temporary variable.

**Example output:**

```
http://myothersite.com/whatIwant
http://myothersite.com/whatIwant2
http://myothersite.com/whatIwant3
```

Comment: Also mention the part `explode('/', $first)[0]` is supported PHP 5.4 onwards.

Comment: Best answer so far bot The links are not in an array they are being edited from a javascript file so they will be in a large variable as text. See Edit.

Comment: Hi @SteveEdwin - please post all relevant information about your problem when you ask the question. As far as this one goes, these answers posted here are all just examples of how you can change the URLs as you requested, you don't need to use the loop or have them in an array. If your links are contained within HTML, I would highly recommend using a DOM parser like DOMDocument, SimpleXML, XPath, etc. It is pretty straightforward to replace HTML attributes using these libraries.

Comment: @scrowler like I said they are not attributes as far as html goes they are plain text to PHP in a variable. I tried to replace the array with the variable and not use the for loop but I didn't have any success.

Comment: With the example you've provided, get the array by `$examples = explode(' ', $examples);`, then instead of `echo`ing the results, add to a temporary array: `$temp[] = //...new url`, then after the loop is finished your new string will be: `$new_string = implode(' ', $temp);`

Answer (score 0):

This function should do the job.

```
<?php
function EditLink($link)
{
    $link = explode("/",$link);
    return $link[4];
}

$new_link = "http://myothersite.com/".EditLink("http://mysite1.com/test/whatIwant/Idontwantthis")."";
echo $new_link;
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this no regex:

```
$urls = array(
    'http://mysite1.com/test/whatIwant3/Idontwantthiseither',
    'http://mysite1.com/test/whatIwant/Idontwantthis',
    'http://mysite1.com/test/whatIwant2/Istilldontwantthis'
);

$new_site = "http://myothersite.com/";

foreach ($urls as $url) {
    $pathinfo = pathinfo($url);

    $base = basename($pathinfo['dirname']);

    $var = str_ireplace($url,  $new_site . $base, $url);

    echo $var . '<br>';
}
```

As of PHP 5.3:

```
$new_urls = array_map(function($url) { // anonymous function
    global $new_site;
    $pathinfo = pathinfo($url);
    $base = basename($pathinfo['dirname']);
    $var = str_ireplace($url,  $new_site . $base, $url);

    return $var;
}, $urls);

echo implode('<br>', $new_urls);
```

Answer (score -1):

Sorry by my last answer, you was right, the order was correct.
Try this one with pre_replace, I beleave could solve the problem:

```
$var = "http://mysite1.com/test/whatIwant/Idontwantthis";
$var = preg_replace("/http\:\/\/mysite1.com\/([^\/]+)\/?.*/", "http://myothersite.com/$1", $var);
echo $var;
```